# Is correct this usage of Class on PHP?

Tags: php

```
class Money {
    private $something;
    private $another;

    public function getSomething() {
        return $this->something;
    }

}

class wallet extends Money{
    private $myAnother;
    private $yourAnother;
    private $money // An Object 

    public function setMoney($money) {
        $this->$money = $money;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMoney() {
        return $this->money; // Object
    }

}
```

So, I'm  using this:

```
$wallet = new Wallet();

print ($wallet ->getMoney()->getSomething());
```

Works fine! But I have no idea if it's the correct way to access the class `Money` which is inside the Wallet.

Comment: change the `$this->$money = $money;` to `$this->money = $money;`.

Comment: also a missing `;` on line `private $money // An Object`

Comment: Thanks, The idea is the usage. I should check for misstype and incorrect code before post

Answer (score 0):

If by the field of `$money` you meant the base class, then **no**; that's not the right way to go. You already have access to the base class in the methods of your child classes, so the field of `$money` is redundant, and you should remove it.

You may initialize your `Money` class using the `__construct()` method, so add the following to your `Money` class:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->something = "something";
    $this->another = "another";
    // anything else needed to initialize this object of Money class..
}
```

In the `wallet` class, in addition to initializing the fields directly inside the class, you need to initialize the base class like the following:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    // anything else needed to initialize this object of wallet class..
}
```

And, as the method of `getSomething()` in the base class of `Money` have the `public` visibility, you can call it directly using `$wallet->getSomething();`.

Comment: I understand. But the idea: I have a class money with methods and I have a class Wallet with another methods. When the Wallet have an Object money. I would access the methods of Money without creating the same methods on the class Wallet. is this possible?

Comment: @Roger When you create a new class by inheritance, like deriving the `wallet` class out of the `Money` class, then an object of `wallet` **is** actually also an object of the `Money` class. In addition to that, when you use inheritance, the client can access all the public methods of the base class through the object of the derived class, and inside the derived class methods, you have access to all non-private fields and methods. That being said, in this perspective you don't need the `$money` field at all.

Comment: @Roger But if you need to use an object of the `Money` class as compounding, then it's totally a new story, in this perspective, you don't need the inheritance at all!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you're getting this to work without instantiating a Money object, and you've got some typos in your code.

But anyway from your last line where you said you want to "access the money which is inside the wallet", your setup doesn't seem to make much sense. A wallet isn't a type of money, so it doesn't seem right that it is extending money.

If you want Money to be a class, you might instead use dependency injection, something like this:

```
class Money {
    private $amount;

    public function add($amount) {
        $this->amount += $amount;
    }

    public function remove($amount) {
        $this->amount -= $amount;
    }

    public function getAmount() {
        return $this->amount;
    }
}

class Wallet {
    private $money; // An Object 

    public function __construct(Money $money) {
        $this->money = $money;
    }

    public function addMoney($amount) {
        $this->money->add($amount);
    }

    public function removeMoney($amount) {
        $this->money->remove($amount);
    }

    public function getMoney() {
        return $this->money->getAmount();
    }
}

$money = new Money();
$wallet = new Wallet($money);

$wallet->addMoney(50);
echo $wallet->getMoney(); // displays 50
$wallet->removeMoney(20);
echo '<br>' . $wallet->getMoney(); // displays 30
```

This way your money is actually inside your wallet and you can play with it however you want.

If you'd rather use the functions in Money directly, you'd have to change the `$money` object `public` in the Wallet class. Then you could do stuff like this:

```
class wallet {
    public $money; // An Object 

    public function __construct(Money $money) {
        $this->money = $money;
    }
}

$money = new Money();
$wallet = new Wallet($money);

$wallet->money->add(50);
echo $wallet->money->getAmount(); // displays 50
$wallet->money->remove(20);
echo '<br>' . $wallet->money->getAmount(); // displays 30
```

Comment: public function __construct(Money $money)  I didn't know how to cast the class like you did. Now works like a charm! Thanks a lot. Sorry I can't upvote because I'm  a new user

Comment: Well, you could mark this as the answer if it adequately answered your question ;)